# How to download a machine learning model from Jupyter notebook?

Tags: file, download, jupyter-notebook

I'm used to working in Colab, where you just do:

```
from google.colab import files
from sklearn.externals import joblib

# save file in colab environment
joblib.dump(model, 'name')

# download to local machine
files.download('name')
```

but I'm not sure what the equivalent is for Jupyter. Does anyone know by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how to download from Google Colab, you can upload your Jupyter Notebook file (.ipynb) in Google Colab and use the same procedures inside Colab to download the model.